# Limitation ot Typescript Set Accessor or issue with my code?

Tags: typescript, accessor

`TypeScript 1.8` I'm trying to wrap my head around how to use the `set` accessor to intercept edit operations on object properties (and sub-properties). It's not working as I expected and I wonder whether there is something wrong with my code.

Here is an excerpt of my class:

```
private setAction:number = 0; //track # of edits

private _person:{ //data to be edited
    name:string,
    data:{
        activities:Array<{
            activityName:string,
            funFactor:number
        }>,
        country:string
    }
};

//public interfaces for set/get operations
public set person(val:any){
    //indicate which edit is occuring
    console.log('setting _person: setAction='+this.setAction);

    if(!this._person) this._person = val;//initial set operation
    let p = this._person;
    p.name = val.name || p.name;
    p.data.activities = val.data.activities || p.data.activities;
    p.data.country = val.data.country || p.data.country;
}

public get person(){
    return this._person;
}

public addActivity(name:string,value:number){
    this.person.data.activities.push(
        {activityName:name,funFactor:value});
}

//Edit this.person and test whether Set Accessor is called
onLoad(){

    console.log('Incrementing setAction to '+ ++this.setAction);
    this.person = {
        name:'Mary',
        data:{
            activities:[],
            country:'Argentina'
        }
    };

    console.log('Incrementing setAction to '+ ++this.setAction);
    this.person.name = 'Janet';

    console.log('Incrementing setAction to '+ ++this.setAction);
    this.addActivity('Bowling',7);

    console.log('Incrementing setAction to '+ ++this.setAction);
    this.person.data.country = 'Mexico';

    console.log('Incrementing setAction to '+ ++this.setAction);
    this.person.data.activities[0].funFactor = 8;

    console.log(this.person);
}
```

When `onLoad` is called, the following is output to the console:

> Incrementing setAction to 1
>
> setting _person: setAction=1
>
> Incrementing setAction to 2
>
> Incrementing setAction to 3
>
> Incrementing setAction to 4
>
> Incrementing setAction to 5
>
> Object {name:"Janet", data:Object}

The `data` in the final `Object` is updated with `country="Mexico"` and Bowling `funFactor=8`.  So all edits were completed successfully, but the `Set` accessor was called only once. Why is this?

A look at [the docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) (scroll down to the *Accessors* section) doesn't mention this limitation.

Additional Notes:
I understand that in order to execute `person.name='Janet'`, I need to first get `person`, so I expect `get` to be called on all those operations. However since `person.name` was changed from 'Mary' to 'Janet', it was indeed **set** to a new value. So why isn't the setter called? I'm struggling with the logic of it. I would expect the process to be: 1) `get person`, 2) `set person.name`.

Shouldn't the getter and the setter both be called when a property is changed from one value to the other?

**Answered**

I always thought `get` and `set` were invoked when properties were read or written. This is how it was explained to me. The TypeScript docs say '*TypeScript supports getters/setters as a way of intercepting accesses to a member of an object*'.  Radim Köhler helped me understand that these functions are invoked when code interacts not with object properties, but with object references.  In short, when I execute `person.name='Janet'`, although the property value changes, `person` still refers to the same object in memory, so there is no `set` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `setter` was called **just once**, at that line

```
this.person = {
    name:'Mary',
    data:{
        activities:[],
        country:'Argentina'
    }
};
```

Each other is in fact calling **`getter`**

```
console.log('Incrementing setAction to '+ ++this.setAction);
this.person.name = 'Janet';

console.log('Incrementing setAction to '+ ++this.setAction);
this.addActivity('Bowling',7);

console.log('Incrementing setAction to '+ ++this.setAction);
this.person.data.country = 'Mexico';

console.log('Incrementing setAction to '+ ++this.setAction);
this.person.data.activities[0].funFactor = 8;
```

Because `this.person.data` is like

```
let person = this.person; // getter
person.data = ...
```

EXTEND

There is [a working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20name%20has%20setter%0D%0A%09private%20_name%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%20name(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%20this._name%20%3D%20name%3B%20console.log(name)%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%09get%20name()%20%7B%20return%20this._name%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20age%20does%20not%20one%0D%0A%09age%3A%20number%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PersonHolder%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20_person%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%20person(person%3A%20Person)%20%7B%20this._person%20%3D%20person%3B%20console.log(JSON.stringify(person))%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%09get%20person()%20%7B%20return%20this._person%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20holder%20%3D%20new%20PersonHolder()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20will%20log%20to%20console%20%7B%20name%3A%20null%2C%20age%3A%20null%7D%0D%0Aholder.person%20%3D%20new%20Person()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20will%20log%20to%20console%20%22new%20name%22%0D%0Aholder.person.name%20%3D%20%22new%20name%22%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20will%20NOT%20log%20to%20console...%20no%20setter%0D%0Aholder.person.age%20%3D%2011%3B) showing the issue in action. When we call setter of the reference property (e.g. Person) we assign a reference. Later, when we change the properties of that referenced object, we do not change the original reference. Check it here:

```
class Person {
    // name has setter
    private _name = null;
    set name(name: string) { this._name = name; console.log(name) };
    get name() { return this._name}

    // age does not one
    age: number = null;
}

class PersonHolder {

    private _person;
    set person(person: Person) { this._person = person; 
                                 console.log(JSON.stringify(person)) };
    get person() { return this._person}
}

var holder = new PersonHolder();

// this will log to console { name: null, age: null}
holder.person = new Person();
// this will log to console "new name"
holder.person.name = "new name"
// this will NOT log to console... no setter
holder.person.age = 11;
```

Live [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20name%20has%20setter%0D%0A%09private%20_name%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%20name(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%20this._name%20%3D%20name%3B%20console.log(name)%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%09get%20name()%20%7B%20return%20this._name%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20age%20does%20not%20one%0D%0A%09age%3A%20number%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PersonHolder%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20_person%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%20person(person%3A%20Person)%20%7B%20this._person%20%3D%20person%3B%20console.log(JSON.stringify(person))%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%09get%20person()%20%7B%20return%20this._person%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20holder%20%3D%20new%20PersonHolder()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20will%20log%20to%20console%20%7B%20name%3A%20null%2C%20age%3A%20null%7D%0D%0Aholder.person%20%3D%20new%20Person()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20will%20log%20to%20console%20%22new%20name%22%0D%0Aholder.person.name%20%3D%20%22new%20name%22%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20will%20NOT%20log%20to%20console...%20no%20setter%0D%0Aholder.person.age%20%3D%2011%3B)

Comment: I understand that in order to execute `person.name='Janet'`, I need to first get `person`, so I expect `get` to be called on all those operations as you mentioned. However since `person.name` was changed from 'Mary' to 'Janet', it was indeed **set** to a new value. So why isn't the setter called? I'm struggling with the logic of it. I would expect the process to be: 1) `get person`, 2) `set person.name`

Comment: Well 1) get person.. means give me reference to person. So we have an address in memory (that is the reference) where person instance is 2) when we change the name.. we do not change that reference to person. It is still the same object.. just somewhere (on the heap) is changed its setting name. So setter of the person.. is realted to reference of the person. Not to the properties related to that instance. Maybe Try to ready something about references and value types. http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/understand-value-and-reference-types-in-javascript/

Comment: I understand a bit about the difference between reference and value types (thanks for the link; I'll take a look).  I didn't know that "*setter is really to reference, not to properties*"  This makes sense but the Typescript docs I linked to don't mention it. Do you have any reference to this that you can add to your answer?

Comment: I would guess, that this is "expected behaviour", expected that reader will understand the concept of reference and its properties. Do not take me wrong.. just trying to say.. that this is related to basic javascript (or JAVA or C#) stuff. Simply changing properties of object (reference) is not calling its own setter. If there will be setters of these properties.. they will be called... hope it helps a bit ;)

Comment: Ok. Please add to your answer the note about how setters/getters deal with object references, not object properties, and how since `person.name='Janet'` doesn't change the reference, the `setter` wasn't called. This answered my question and I'd like to select your answer.

Comment: I created an example and show in action how the setters with references do work.. hope that helps